# MySQL Advanced Ranks Query

Tags: mysql, ranking

I have a table that looks like this:

```
map         uid     time    name
'first'     1       5.0     'Jon'
'first'     3       4.9     'Robin'
'second'    1       2.0     'Jon'
'first'     2       5.3     'Max'
'second'    3       2.1     'Robin'
```

I am currently selecting the values using this:

```
SELECT records.* FROM `records` WHERE `uid` = '3' ORDER BY `records`.`time` ASC
```

Now obviously, I have multiple uids for different maps. How would I find the rank of every user out of total ranks? I know I can find total ranks of the map by using `COUNT(DISTINCT map)`. However, I am having issues selecting a specific user and their rank in the map. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:
Desired output when selecting uid 3 is as follows:

```
map         uid     time    name        position    totalposition (totalposition would be COUNT(DISTINCT map))
'first'     3       4.9     'Robin'     2           3
'second'    3       2.1     'Robin'     2           2
```

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected output

Comment: how do you want to calculate the rank ?

Comment: By the least time, so #1 user will be the one with the lowest time

Comment: I updated the desired output and table to better explain what I need.

Comment: Rank you may have to calculate in the php / any programming language or refer to Mysql User Defined Variables http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: I can definitely do that, I just thought it'd be simpler and more efficient to do it MySQL side.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query : -

```
mysql> set @pos = 0; select records.*, @pos:=@pos+1 as position from records order by time desc;
```

**Output :**

```
+--------+------+------+-------+--------------+
| map    | uid  | time | name  | position     |
+--------+------+------+-------+--------------+
| first  |    2 | 5.30 | Max   |            1 |
| first  |    1 | 5.00 | jon   |            2 |
| first  |    3 | 4.90 | Robin |            3 |
| second |    3 | 2.10 | Robin |            4 |
| second |    1 | 2.00 | Jon   |            5 |
+--------+------+------+-------+--------------+
```

And now, to recieve position of a particular :

```
mysql> set @pos = 0; select * from (select records.*, @pos:=@pos+1 as position
mysql> from records order by time desc) as t where uid = 3;
```

**Output :**

```
+--------+------+------+-------+----------+
| map    | uid  | time | name  | position |
+--------+------+------+-------+----------+
| first  |    3 | 4.90 | Robin |        3 |
| second |    3 | 2.10 | Robin |        4 |
+--------+------+------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for, maps should be distinct for position. Max position should be 3, since there are only 3 values for the map "first". Also, I want to select the UID with the position, not run a full query of all values. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for adding the particular user query! But position still isn't distinct for the map :( It just gives the position out of all maps.